# After Effects / ExtendScript: Using libraries and importing .jsx files?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects, jsx

*I am new to After Effects scripting but have much experience with JavaScript in the browser.*

1. How do I import .jsx files?
2. Can I use js libraries such as underscore.js etc?
3. What are some good resources for AE scripting? (Ideally infographics projects)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. To include a .jsx next to your script

use:

```
#include "includeme.jsx"
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can also include files using the following syntax:

```
//@include "includeme.jsx"
```

Which (IMHO) is the better way. It wont break a linter and is more javascript-ish.

2. You can use plain old javascript (ES3 Syntax). If the libraries you include use some browser specific js (like `console.log()`) you will get an error
3. Best resource is the [After Effects scripting guide](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/index.html). There are also lots of open source scripts on http://aescripts.com that you can examine

**EDIT 1:**  You can also include a file like this.

```
var path = ((File($.fileName)).path); // this is the path of the script
// now build a path to another js file
// e.g. json lib https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
var libfile = File(path +'/_libs/json2.js');
if(libfile.exists){
  $.evalFile(libfile);
}
```

**Edit 3:** Old link to AE scripting docs was broken. Updated the link

Comment: Thanks Fabian! I tried that earlier but then it didn't work. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Will the `//@` syntax work for other pre-processor directives, such as `#target indesign` or `#strict on`?

Comment: @Sturm I think //@target works. //@strict I don't know. Why don't you give it a try and report back? ;)

Comment: @fabianmoronzirfas, I can't tell any difference. With that line, deleting that line, changing it to `#strict off`, etc. The command (when set to 'on') is supposed to throw a runtime error when an attempt is made in the script to write to a read-only property. I put in the line `app.activeScriptUndoMode = UndoModes.AUTO_UNDO;` near the top of the script to test it. However, I get the error no matter what that `#strict` line is.

Comment: poor old extendscript. It is so broken in some parts. Thanks for the report

Comment: Modern link to the AE Scripting guide, since the one in the answer is rotten: https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/index.html